# What does excessive correlated residuals (as indicated by modification index) say about a model?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, residuals, confirmatory-factor

This question/post is a follow-up to a few previous posts so please forgive the redundancy.

My question is what excessive number of modification indices suggesting high number of correlated errors may say about a factor model (CFA). I will add that the situation concerns the presence of high number of mod indices despite good overall model fit:

My reading of the following posts was that correlated errors may reflect a problem with the model or the indicators, that may otherwise not be reflected in the overall fit of the models. However, I am unclear on this and would very much appreciate some explanation

1) [Why is error variance important in CFA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101473/why-is-error-variance-important-in-cfa)

2) [Impact of correlated errors in CFA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163775/impact-of-correlated-errors-in-cfa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with a lot of correlated errors *if they are justified*. The problem with correlated errors is that you have a model that you have a theoretical reason for liking, but it doesn't fit.

The fact that your model doesn't fit means that the model is wrong. But instead of accepting that, you stick in correlated errors until it does fit, but all that you have done is overfit the model - the model will not cross-validate (but cross-validation is rare in CFA).

Comment: THANK YOU for your response. I have a more detailed description posted elsewhere( http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214667/reporting-focal-strain-high-mi-for-cfa-models-with-good-model-fit) but the overall model fit is good according to CFI, TLI, S-RMR, RMSEA. Despite these indicators, is the model still considered poorly fitting due to these modification indIces? The correlated errors do make sense (mostly related within same factor) but my preference would be to leave them alone if this can be justified. I am just concerned with the sheer number of those that exceed MI>10.

Comment: Does this mean that I should dismiss the overall fit and accept that the model is actually poorly fitting? How do I reconcile the overall fit vs. localized fit discrepancy?

Comment: A modification index needs to be higher than 10 in a sample of 799 before I worry about it much.